# Is this VHDL code making an assignment conflict?

Tags: vhdl, assign

In VHDL and other hardware languages, it is my understanding that all conditions from true logic in a process happen at the same time. I have a std_logic FLAG variable that appears to me to have a conflict. I saw this code in a publication and I do not understand it. It looks like the FLAG variable can be assigned two values. Is this bad code or am I missing something? (The Process has some input triggers but no CLK.)
The variable names were changed to protect the innocent.

```
... 

process(op_state, ...)
begin
    FLAG <= '0';

    case op_state is
        when STATE_SLEEP =>
            FLAG <= '1';

    when    some other cases not containing FLAG

    end case;
end process;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume both assignments are in the same process.

That coding style is allowed. If there are multiple assignment in a process the LAST one 'wins' from the previous one. This is even on part of a vector.

I often use this to set a default:

```
  -- Default set all read bits to zero 
  axil_rdata<= (others => '0');

  case (radrs) is                                     
  when X"00" => axil_rdata( 7 downto 0) <= control;   
  when X"04" => axil_rdata(15 downto 0) <= status;
  when X"08" => axil_rdata              <= counter;
  ...
```

Thus all bits of `axil_rdata` are first set to zero. Then some bits get assigned a new value.

Comment: It is the same process. The auto editor changed it. I have read so many works on VHDL and a lot talk is on an else other clause to cover all bases at the bottom. I will always remember, :the LAST one 'wins'".